# 100% discount on a one off charge with Stripe [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

In my Laravel application I have a page where users must pay £150 for a membership fee. To process this payment I chose Stripe.

I store all of the charges in a payments table, along with a user's ID.

**Payments table**

```
Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->uuid('user_id');
    $table->string('transaction_id');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->string('amount');
    $table->string('currency');
    $table->datetime('date_recorded');
    $table->string('card_brand');
    $table->string('card_last_4', 4);
    $table->string('status');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I also implemented a voucher system of my own as I am not using subscriptions.

**Voucher table**

```
Schema::create('vouchers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('code');
    $table->integer('discount_percent');
    $table->dateTime('expires_on');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Payment Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use App\Payment;
use App\Voucher;
use App\Mail\User\PaymentReceipt;
use App\Mail\Admin\UserMembershipPaid;
use Log;
use Mail;
use Validator;
use Stripe;
use Stripe\Error\Card;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Set an initial amount to be used by the controller
     *
     * @var float
     */
    private $amount = 150.00;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('verified');
        $this->middleware('is_investor');
        $this->middleware('is_passive_member');
    }

    /**
     * Display a form allowing a user to make a payment
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function showPaymentForm()
    {
        return view('user.payment');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an entered voucher code by the user
     * Either calculate a discount or skip the payment form 
     *
     * @param [type] $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function processVoucher(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'code' => 'required|exists:vouchers',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'code.required' => 'You submitted a blank field',
            'code.exists' => 'This voucher code is not valid'
        ];

        Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages)->validate();

        $entered_voucher_code = $request->get('code');

        $voucher = Voucher::where('code', $entered_voucher_code)->where('expires_on', '>', Carbon::now())->first();

        // If the voucher exists
        if ($voucher) {
            $discount_percent = $voucher->discount_percent;
            $new_amount = $this->amount - ($discount_percent / 100 * $this->amount);

            // As Stripe won't handle charges of 0, we need some extra logic
            if ($new_amount <= 0.05) {
                $this->upgradeAccount(auth()->user());

                Log::info(auth()->user()->log_reference . " used voucher code {$voucher->code} to get a 100% discount on their Active membership");

                return redirect()->route('user.dashboard')->withSuccess("Your membership has been upgraded free of charge.");
            }
            // Apply the discount to this session 
            else {
                Log::info(auth()->user()->log_reference . " used voucher code {$voucher->code} to get a {$voucher->discount_percent}% discount on their Active membership");

                // Store some data in the session and redirect
                session(['voucher_discount' => $voucher->discount_percent]);
                session(['new_price' => $this->amount - ($voucher->discount_percent / 100) * $this->amount]);

                return redirect()->back()->withSuccess([
                    'voucher' => [
                        'message' => 'Voucher code ' . $voucher->code . ' has been applied. Please fill in the payment form',
                        'new_price' => $new_amount
                    ]
                ]);
            }
        }
        // Voucher has expired
        else {
            return redirect()->back()->withError('This voucher code has expired.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle a Stripe payment attempt from the Stripe Elements form
     * Takes into account voucher codes if they are less than 100%
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleStripePayment(Request $request)
    {
        // Retreive the currently authenticated user
        $user = auth()->user();

        // Get the Stripe token from the request
        $token = $request->get('stripeToken');

        // Set the currency for your country
        $currency = 'GBP';

        // Set an initial amount for Stripe to use with the charge
        $amount = $this->amount;

        // A description for this payment
        $description = "Newable Private Investing Portal - Active Membership fee";

        // Initialize Stripe with given public key
        $stripe = Stripe::make(config('services.stripe.secret'));

        // Attempt a charge via Stripe
        try {
            Log::info("{$user->log_reference} attempted to upgrade their membership to Active");

            // Check that token was sent across, if it wasn't, stop
            if (empty($token)) {
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                    'error' => "Token error, do you have JavaScript disabled?"
                ]);
            }

            // Check whether a discount should be applied to this charge
            if (session()->has('voucher_discount')) {
                $discount_percentage = session()->pull('voucher_discount');

                $discount = ($discount_percentage / 100) * $amount;

                $amount = $amount - $discount;

                session()->forget('new_price');
            }

            // Create a charge with an idempotent id to prevent duplicate charges
            $charge = $stripe->idempotent(session()->getId())->charges()->create([
                'amount' => $amount,
                'currency' => $currency,
                'card' => $token,
                'description' => $description,
                'statement_descriptor' => 'Newable Ventures',
                'receipt_email' => $user->email
            ]);

            //If the payment is successful, store the payment, send some emails and upgrade this user
            if ($charge['status'] == 'succeeded') {
                $this->storePayment($charge);

                Mail::send(new PaymentReceipt($user));
                Mail::send(new UserMembershipPaid($user));

                $this->upgradeAccount($user);

                return redirect()->route('user.dashboard')->withSuccess("Your payment was successful, you will soon recieve an email receipt.");
            // If the payment was unsuccessful
            } else {
                $this->storePayment($charge);

                Log::error("Stripe charge failed for {$user->log_reference}");

                return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                    'error' => "Unfortunately, your payment was unsuccessful."
                ]);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error("Error attempting Stripe Charge for {$user->log_reference} - Exception - error details {$e->getMessage()}");

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        } catch (\Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\MissingParameterException $e) {
            Log::error("Error attempting Stripe Charge for {$user->log_reference} - MissingParameterException - error details {$e->getMessage()}");

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        } catch (\Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\CardErrorException $e) {
            Log::error("Error attempting Stripe Charge for {$user->log_reference} - CardErrorException - error details {$e->getMessage()}");

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        } catch (\Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\ApiLimitExceededException $e) {
            Log::error("Error attempting Stripe Charge for {$user->log_reference} - ApiLimitExceededException - error details {$e->getMessage()}");

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        } catch (\Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\BadRequestException $e) {
            Log::error("Error attempting Stripe Charge for {$user->log_reference} - BadRequestException -  error details {$e->getMessage()}");

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        } catch (\Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\ServerErrorException $e) {
            Log::error("Error attempting Stripe Charge for {$user->log_reference} - ServerErrorException - error details: {$e->getMessage()}");

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        } catch (\Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\UnauthorizedException $e) {
            Log::error("Error attempting Stripe Charge for {$user->log_reference} - UnauthorizedException - error details: {$e->getMessage()}");

            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store a Stripe chargee in our database so we can reference it later if necessary
     * Charges stored against users for cross referencing and easy refunds
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function storePayment(array $charge)
    {
        $payment = new Payment();

        $payment->transaction_id = $charge['id'];
        $payment->description = $charge['description'];
        $payment->amount = $charge['amount'];
        $payment->currency = $charge['currency'];
        $payment->date_recorded = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($charge['created']);
        $payment->card_brand = $charge['source']['brand'];
        $payment->card_last_4 = $charge['source']['last4'];
        $payment->status = $charge['status'];

        auth()->user()->payments()->save($payment);

        if ($payment->status === "succeeded") {
            Log::info("Successful Stripe Charge recorded for {$user->log_reference} with Stripe reference {$payment->transaction_id} using card ending {$payment->card_last_4}");
        } else {
            Log::info("Failed Stripe Charge recorded for {$user->log_reference} with Stripe reference {$payment->transaction_id} using card ending {$payment->card_last_4}");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle a user account upgrade from whatever to Active
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return void
     */
    private function upgradeAccount(User $user)
    {
        $current_membership_type = $user->member_type;

        $user->member_type = "Active";

        $user->save();

        Log::info("{$user->log_reference} has been upgraded from a {$current_membership_type} member to an Active Member.");
    }
}
```

`processVoucher()` takes a string entered by the user, checks to see if it exists in the `vouchers` table and then applies the discount percentage to the fee of `150.00`.

It then adds the new value to the session and I use that in the Stripe Charge.

**The issue**

The issue is that Stripe's minimum chargable amount is `0.05`, so to circumvent this issue I've just called a method that upgrades the account.

I should, in theory, store the free upgrades in the `charges` table but I would end up with multiple null values.

Is this a horrible solution?

In the `User` model I also have the following methods:

```
/**
 * Relationship to payments
 */
public function payments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Payment::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * Relationship to payments to get most recent payment
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function latest_payment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Payment::class, 'user_id', 'id')->latest();
}
```

These are used so I can calculate when a user last made a payment, as I needed to bill them annually without using subscriptions as users can also use 100% off vouchers to upgrade.

I made this console command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use App\Payment;
use Log;

class ExpireMembership extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'membership:expire';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Expire user memberships after 1 year of being Active.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //Retrieve all users who are an active member with their list of payments
        $activeUsers = User::where('member_type', 'Active')->get();

        //Get current date
        $current_date = Carbon::now();

        foreach($activeUsers as $user){
            $this->info("Checking user {$user->log_reference}");

            // If a user has at least one payment recorded
            if($user->payments()->exists()){
                //Get membership end date (latest payment + 1 year added)
                $membership_end_date = $user->payments
                    ->where('description', 'Newable Private Investing Portal - Active Membership fee')
                    ->sortByDesc('created_at')
                    ->first()->created_at->addYear();
            }
            // If the user has no payments but is an active member just check if they're older than a year
            else{
                $membership_end_date = $user->created_at->addYear();
            }
            //If the membership has gone over 1 year, expire the membership.
            if ($current_date->lessThanOrEqualTo($membership_end_date)) {
                $user->member_type = "Passive";
                $user->save();

                $this->info($user->log_reference . "membership has expired and membership status has been set to Passive.");

                Log::info($user->log_reference . "membership has expired and membership status has been set to Passive.");

            }
        }

        $this->info("Finished checking user memberships.");

    }
}
```

Users who use vouchers do not have payments, so figuring out when to bill them automatically is tricky.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you need to use one-time payments if you're building a subscription system. Why can't you use Stripe subscriptions? They offer everything you need based on your description here. If you can offer more insight that would be helpful.

Comment: Building a subscription system with Stripe but not using Stripe subscription billing <insert confused Jackie Chan meme>

Comment: I'll add more clarity but it's essentially because the business area can't decide whether they actually want subscriptions or not, and there's odd business logic as to whether they have to pay or not.

Comment: But yes... I know it sounds stupid, but essentially should i store a voucher usage in my payments table?

Comment: Stripe offer a bunch of different functionality that allow a lot of flexibility when building payment systems. The business might not be sure if they want subscriptions or one-off payments but that doesn't need to determine how you build the system. You can use trials and discounts within the Stripe subscription system to grant free periods and prevent automatic renewal. You should build the system using Stripe subscriptions and then if the business decide "actually, we want one-off payments" you can simply write a little bit of code to prevent subscriptions from renewing...

Comment: ...and if the business decide they _do_ want subscriptions, then great, you've already built the system to do what they want. The idea you've proposed here would _work_ but it's a bad approach that will cause you headaches and if they do decide "actually we want subscriptions" you've got to refactor a bunch.